# Make user-submitted links live (i.e. clickable) in a django app

Tags: python, html, django

This question is for django ninjas: I have an app (djagno 1.4) that allows users to create posts. These posts have a number of fields, including several CharFields.

My problem is this: when a user creates a new post and pastes a live link into one of these post CharFields, I want that link to be live and clickable as soon as its up. On doing some research I saw [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/) how to deal with the same problem in php.

Can someone help me out, or point me in the right direction to some documentation? I can't find any on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the urlize filter, so, let's say your `Post` model has a field called `text`, then in your template you'd do this:

```
{{ post_obj.text|urlize }}
```